# Why can't I see my published app in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I made a web browser called Byte and It got published, but I can't find it in the Ubuntu Software Center or on the Ubuntu Software Catalog. Does it take a while for it to update?

Comment: In which sense published? Where did you publish it?

Comment: I uploaded it to developer.ubuntu.com and the status says "Published".

Answer (score 0):

You mean [this Byte browser](https://uappexplorer.com/app/byte-terabytestudios.terabytestudios)?

You created a click package and uploaded it to the click store. It will never appear in the *Ubuntu Software Center*, as that is for traditional Debian packaged applications. Apps packaged as clicks will appear in the click store scope in Unity8.

If you wish to ship your application in *Ubuntu Software Center*, you will need to create a traditional Debian package, following the guidelines on the [developer site](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/). You can upload the package through that site.

If your application is not suitable for use on phones and tablets, you might want to remove the click application you uploaded, from the store, so that others don't install it and end up with an app which doesn't work on their devices.

Comment: Oh, how do I upload to the Ubuntu Software Center then?

Comment: I figured it out, I'm supposed to click "Desktop". That's kinda stupid it takes you to Snappy by default.